# Json Hive: Need a function to find length of list in json

Tags: json, list, hive

I have a json list which has to be unlisted. Right now I am using get_json_object() but it is a cumber-son process as I don't know the length of list . In the code I pasted it is 3 but it can got up to 50. How Do i know the latest version number

```
get_json_object(description,'$.data.info[3].version')
```

I need the number 3 or version 1567954261

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "info": [
            { "version": 1567904215, "amount": 1987 },
            { "version": 1567943816, "amount": 169 },
            { "version": 1567954261, "amount": 3034 }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In JS it would be $.data.info.length-1 (last one), but do not know the rest so in case it would work as in JS last item should be something like this get_json_object(description,'$.data.info['+($.data.info.length-1) + '].version')